# Compare uploaded CSV file with database table

Tags: java, csv

i have the following problem.
I have a  GUI where the user can upload some csv file and this file where store in my database. In the same time, the file is checked if the ID which is the first column in the uploaded file, is also stored in my database table, which holds about 700.000 records. So i want to compare any line in the uploading file with my database ID column. Now i have, for testing, export the table from my database and narrowed them, just for testing. But if i upload this file and the want to compare, it dosen't hit any ID - althought it is the same file, just smaller.

Here's my code:

```
String line = null;
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\auditUp\\gef.txt"));
        EntityManager emt = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transcation = emt.getTransaction();
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {

            i++;
            String[] content = line.split(";"); 

            if(content.length < 2)
            {
                System.out.println("Ende");                 
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                reader.close();
                return;
            }

            transcation.begin();
            TypedQuery<Datensatz> q = emt.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Datensatz d WHERE d.Id = :Id",Datensatz.class);
            q.setParameter("Id", content[0]);
            List<Datensatz> gefunden =  q.getResultList();
            transcation.commit();
            if(!gefunden.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                out.write(i + ": " + gefunden);
                out.newLine();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Liste ist leer");
            }

        }
        emt.close();
        reader.close();


        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            fis.close();
            if(out != null)
            {
                try {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

My Entity Class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Datensatz implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String Id;
private String Relative_ID;
private String Title;
private String Gender;
private String First_Name;
private String Last_Name;
private String Full_Name;
private String Other_Names;
private String Alternative_Script;
private String Function;
private String Category;
private String DOB;
private String POB;
private String Country;
private String Code;
private String Additional_Information;
private String Country_Of_Origin;
private String Country_Of_Activity;

[getter and setter]

}
```

Comment: Hallo! Try just 1 entry, test the create, save delete, then test creating a csv file from an entry, and uploading a csv file from an entry. Write a test for selecting entries from your database too. There should be a test to an interface which does these things. With the information provided there is no way to know what of the many things which can go wrong, is wrong, you need stop trying to do everything in 1 go, and break it up.

Comment: What does comparing CSV data to database have to do with GUI and JSF?

Comment: Please, use `emt.createQuery` once, and put inside while only `q.setParameter("Id", content[0]);`, also, is your application concurrent? if not, you don't need to put a select statement in transaction context.

Comment: Show a sample of your ID's, both the ones in the file and DB